# How to constantly update and push data with WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a `ws.js` which is my server:

```
// A simple server-side script.
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 3000 });

let number = 0.0;

function updateNumber(){
    number = Math.random().toFixed(4);
}

// Desperetly tried this.
var emitter = function() {}

var emission = function(data) {
  emitter(data);
}

// Then my WebSocket stuff.
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    emitter = function(data) {
        wss.clients.forEach(function(client) {
            // ---> How to constantly run updateNumber()
            // As long as connection is live.
            console.log(data);
            // Debug
            console.log('[server:onConnect] Received request.');
            // Send the transmission.
            console.log('[server:onConnection] Sending:', number);
            client.send(number);
        });
    }
});
```

I have to do this without using `setInterval()` as the number will be coming from a file that is constantly being updated.

So in my server's verbosity stream, in the terminal I get this, once the client connects in:

```
[server:onConnection] Sending: 0.9569
[server:onConnect] Received request.
[server:onConnection] Sending: 0.4058
[server:onConnect] Received request.
[server:onConnection] Sending: 0.7813
[server:onConnect] Received request.
[server:onConnection] Sending: 0.9672
[server:onConnect] Received request.
[server:onConnection] Sending: 0.0671
[server:onConnect] Received request.
[server:onConnection] Sending: 0.5682
[server:onConnect] Received request.
[server:onConnection] Sending: 0.0171
```

--- UPDATE ---

The problem is fixed when I tweaked the `updateNumber()` function as:

```
function updateNumber(){
    number = Math.random().toFixed(4);
    emission();
}
```

This seems to be successfully bridging the `emitter` function burred inside the `on connect` block and the `updateNumber()` function.

However, this solution still requires a `setInterval()` to run the `updateNumber()` in order to create the emission of a constantly changing number. Is there a way to create a function that runs and constantly emits a random number, without using `setInterval()`.